# Executing Append Query not doing anything

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Executing Append Query not doing anything

I'm having an odd problem that just reared its ugly head for some reason. I have a form that is used to add/edit/delete records in tblWorkOrder. When the record is saved, a check is made to see if the companion record in tblServiceRecord exists, and if not (like if it were the first time the record in tblWorkOrder is being saved/input) it will execute a query (qryCreateSR).

Several weeks ago it worked just fine. I had no problems with it, but then I updated tblServiceRecord to add several new columns and now it's not working at all. However, the SQL for the query doesn't delineate any of these new columns, let alone any specific information from tblWorkOrder. So I'm not entirely sure how this bug came up.

Here is the SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblServiceRecord ( WorkOrderID )
SELECT Forms![frmWorkOrders].Form![txtID];
```

And here is the code behind the command button:

```vb
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    If DCount("*", "[tblServiceRecord]", "[WorkOrderID] = " & [Forms]![frmWorkOrders].[Form]![txtID]) > 0 Then
        Else
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryCreateSR"
    End If

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    Me.lstWorkOrders.Requery
    Me.lstWorkOrders.Value = ""
    Me.txtComments.Value = ""

cmdSave_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdSave_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdSave_Click_Exit
End Sub
```

---

After removing the warnings suppression I get a **key violation issue**.

No clue what is causing the key violations.  I checked my tables, and the two tables in question are `tblWorkOrder` and `tblServiceRecord`.  Both have no records in them, I compacted the database, the linked fields (in `tblServiceRecord`, there is a reference to `tblWorkOrder` with the field `WorkOrderID`) are set to the same data type (number), and the child-tables are set to Indexed (No).

Just in case anyone wants to look at the database itself, here is a link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_T-G9fyYQYjH3-YBe4PXhbBDTKNmY3ce

Comment: Some of the new columns could be "Required", i.e. are not allowed to be empty.

Comment: Leave Warnings on and see what messages pop up. When you turn Warnings off should turn back on after query executes.

Comment: I edited the entire question to the "real" problem.  Thanks @June7 for setting my derp moment straight.

Comment: I see that you are setting two controls to empty string. Are these bound or unbound? I expect txtComments at least is bound. If bound, why would you need to set its value? This potentially saves empty string into record and I recommend not allowing empty strings in records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving the current record in the form (by setting `Me.Dirty = False`), **before** inserting the record to the other table. Since you try to insert into  a child table with a relation to a parent table, you must have a corresponding (saved) record in the parent table. When you create a new entry in the form, it first doesn't exist in the table until it is saved for the first time.

```vb
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
    Me.Dirty = False ' Or DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord    <==== Save here
    If DCount("*", "[tblServiceRecord]", "[WorkOrderID] = " & [Forms]![frmWorkOrders].[Form]![txtID]) = 0 Then
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryCreateSR"
    End If

    'Removed: DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord   <==== instead of here
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    Me.lstWorkOrders.Requery
    Me.lstWorkOrders.Value = ""
    Me.txtComments.Value = ""

cmdSave_Click_Exit:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Exit Sub

cmdSave_Click_Err: // This code will never run, since a "On Error Goto cmdSave_Click_Err" is missing
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdSave_Click_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks!!

Comment: Because, if the OP saved twice or was editing an already existing record, then it would have worked. Probably later, he tested the code with a new record and didn't notice this subtle difference.